# stored procedures in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to know **WHERE** to write stored procedures in PostgreSQL?
I mean not how to write but the very basic thing where to write, where to go if I want to write one?

Is it written just like query or in some different sort of file?
I am fairly new to postgresql 
So please explain as much as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use any text editor to create a (SQL) file containing the necessary CREATE FUNCTION statement.

Then run that file using psql.

As an alternative you can use a GUI tool like pgAdmin or something similar ([Squirrel](http://www.squirrelsql.org/), [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/), [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net), ...) where you have the editor "built-in"
You can directly run the statement that you edit against the database.

Answer (score 3):

Use the CREATE FUNCTION... command in whatever your prefered PSQL manager is.

Something like this (psuedo SQL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    MyProc(text, text)
RETURNS
    void
AS
    $delimiter$
    INSERT INTO MyTable (text_val_1, text_val_2)
    VALUES ($1, $2);
    $delimiter$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

More info can be found here:

http://www.day32.com/MySQL/Meetup/Presentations/postgresql_stored_procedures.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to open pgAdmin application which you need to install if you do not have it.

Then you need click on this button as I have marked and then a query editor will appear at right side. You will write your query or stored procedure or functions here in this query editor.

See the screenshot attached :

[image: pgAdmin : Query Editor to write queries]